# Different headers in CTreeCtrl

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, treeview

I use CTreeCtrl in two applications, one my own and second the sample one. In both are different visual of headers - one is older typ from Win XP, second is modern typ from current versions of windows - see pictures below. I did not found difference in settings. Sure I use for both one computer, the same versions of windows (11) and Visual Studio (2019).
Where I can set this visual?

[image: My Own]
[image: Sample]

Comment: Check linker settings, in particular `Generate manifest` and `Manifest file`. [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview)

Comment: Is your CTreeCtrl a custom control? When creating MFC, there is visual style in the options. You can use  `SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L" ", L" ");` turn off visual style.

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[Themes and Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/visual-styles-overview#themes-and-visual-styles) shows the difference between configured and not configured to use visual styles.

The following illustration shows a simple dialog box with a taskbar, on a Windows 7 desktop that uses the Windows Aero theme without transparency. Because the application is not configured to use visual styles, the buttons appear the same regardless of the theme settings.

[image]

In contrast, the following illustration shows the same dialog box on the same desktop, but this time the application has been configured to work with visual styles. Note the different appearance of the buttons in the client area. The buttons look different because the system has applied the visual styles that are defined in the Aero theme.

[image]

The following example shows a similar dialog box on a Windows 8 desktop. In Windows 8, visual styles are always on, so Windows 8 apps get theming "for free".

[image]

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) to go on how to enable or disable visual styles.

You can turn off visual styles for a control or for all controls in a window by calling the [**SetWindowTheme**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme) function.